# What is this 1x2 hinge brick?

Tags: part-identification

What are the two pieces that make up this hinge and brick?

[image: Pieces]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a 1x2 hinge brick. Here's a better image of what you're looking at:

[image: 3937 + 3938]

This is part [3937](http://brickset.com/parts/design-3937) and [3938](http://brickset.com/parts/design-3938). Here are the two parts viewed separately:

[image: 3938]

[image: 3937]